# How to retrieve maillist into one field?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I want to retrieve the mail list into one field and display the data retrieved.

The mail list is represented as an array, and I want all data to be in one field.

```
define variable i    as integer  no-undo.                                           
define variable cmmt as longchar no-undo. 
cmmt = " ". 

for each cd_det no-lock
  where cd_ref = "test1"
  and   cd_type   = "EL":

    do i = 1 to extent(cd_cmmt):
      cmmt = cmmt + cd_cmmt[i].
    end.
    disp cmmt.

end.
```

I tried the above code, but it doesn't display. Instead, `test1` record contains 2 mails (`gangadhar.pichika-external@gemalto.com,balkrishna.talapalliwar-
external@gemalto.com`), but I didn’t get that data in `cmmt`.

Comment: I wonder the code actually compiles. Try to remove the "else" within the do i = 1 to extent (cd_cmmt) loop. An "else" should only be followed an "if".

Comment: sorry it's typo mistake i updated the code

Answer (score 0):

A LONGCHAR variable cannot be displayed (unless using a large editor widget). Try to DISPLAY STRING(cmmt).

Comment: No i got 'gangadha' in output

Comment: i tried with character format x(78) instead of longchar then also i got upto 78 characters and here 78 is the maximus characters for displaying frame

Comment: hi @Mike Fenchner actually in cd_det where cd_ref = test1 "gangadhar.pichika-external@gemalto.com,balkrishna.talapalliwar- external@gemalto.com" this is the data so now i want to retrieve that data in to one field is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you expect with "retrieve that data in to one field"? After running that code you should have all Email adresses concatenated in cmmt. You might want to use a delimiter (comma or NL)